# How to implement a button in flask without rendering the template?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm very new to Python & Flask and as of rn I'm trying to build a website which generates random colour with a press of a button, but the idea is that you can also save those random colours on your profile and later on manage them (delete, move around, etc).

The problem I'm facing now is on my "randomise" page I can't seem to figure out how to implement a *save button* without rendering the whole page, randomising the colour again and therefore "saving" wrong colour into the database. Here's what I have so far:

**app.py**

```
@app.route("/l_randomize", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def l_randomize():
if request.method == "GET":
    return render_template("l_randomize.html")
else:
    color = '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(*random.sample(range(256), 3))
    if 'favourite' in request.form:
        db.execute("INSERT INTO fav (user_id, color) VALUES (:user_id, :color)", user_id=session["user_id"], color=color)
    return render_template("l_randomized.html",color=color)
```

**app.html**

```
{%block body%}
<div class="container">
<h3>Your color is</h3>
<div id="l_randomized" style="background-color: {{ color }};">
<form method="post" action="/l_randomize">
    <input type="submit" name = "randomize" value="Randomize" >
    <input type="submit" name = "favourite" value="Favourite" >
</form>
</div>
</div>
{%endblock%}
```

I kind of understand the flaw in code that I already wrote and why it's rendering the template again, but I just need a hint or where to look at, so after that *if statement* it wouldn't refresh the page or go further. Any suggestions, comments and hints on how to implement this better are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a lot trickier than you imagine. You will need to use some kind of asynchronous update. In this case, without learning React *et al.* it's probably easier to use JQuery. Essentially, you want to intercept your form submission to save the favourite colour (note, I'm in the UK so my spelling is probably inconsistent in the below example, sorry) and then only change a particular element in the DOM.

There's a lot of code below, but it makes a self-contained example - just run the script and go to `127.0.0.1:5000`. The major changes:

1. I've switched to the Flask-SQLAlchemy ORM (Object-relational Mapper). This was partly just because it's easier for me to set up a minimal example, but it's also usually easier in app development. So, I've made two classes that will create the database tables for you.
2. I've implemented two JavaScript functions that use AJAX. One is attached to a button click, the other intercepts a form submission.
3. I've split the Flask routes up so that different events can be handled separately

Essentially:

1. If we don't know the user's favourite colour, we'll just give a white background.
2. If they select a new colour at random, we'll update the background colour *only*. We'll also update a hidden field in the form that saves their preference, in case that's the one they want to keep.
3. If they click "favourite", we'll write that to the database. If you close the page and open it again after this point, you'll notice that we load their previous favourite

Don't use `render_template_string` in your actual code, it just allowed me to put the template into a single script.

**This is for illustrative purposes only. The intention is to connect dots on the general setup; it's missing things like form validation, amongst other things.**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, session, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

import random

# =============================================================================
# BASIC APP INIT
# =============================================================================
db = SQLAlchemy()

app = Flask('__main__')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'change_me'
db.init_app(app)

# =============================================================================
# DATABASE MODELS
# =============================================================================
class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String)
    

class Fav(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id')) 
    color = db.Column(db.String)

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

    user = Users(username='testing') # Create a fake user
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()

# =============================================================================
# TEMPLATE
# =============================================================================

l_randomize_html = """
{%block body%}
<div class="container">
   <h3>Your color is</h3>
   <div id="l_randomized" style="background-color: {{ color }};">
      <button onclick="changeColor()">Change</button>
      <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('l_save_favourite') }}" id="favColorForm">
         <input type="hidden" name="currentColor" id="currentColor" value="{{ color }}">
         <input type="submit" name="favourite" value="Favourite" >
      </form>
      <div id="colorSaveResp"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
   function changeColor() {
       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: "{{ url_for('change_color') }}",
           success: function(color) {
               $("#currentColor").val(color);
               $("#l_randomized").css("backgroundColor", color);
           }
       });
   }
</script>
<script>
   $("#favColorForm").submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var form = $(this);
       var url = form.attr('action');
    
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: form.serialize(),
           context: form,
           success: function(resp) {
               $("#dynamic_div").html(resp);    
           }
       });
   });
</script>
{%endblock%}
"""

# =============================================================================
# ROUTES
# =============================================================================

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def l_randomize():
    session['user_id'] = 1 # Add to the session
    # See whether we have a favourite colour 
    favourite = Fav.query.filter_by(user_id=session['user_id']).first()
    if favourite:
        color = favourite.color
    else:
        # They don't, give a default
        color = '#FFF' 
    return render_template_string(l_randomize_html, color=color)


@app.route('/change_color', methods=['POST'])
def change_color():
    return '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(*random.sample(range(256), 3))


@app.route('/save_color', methods=['POST'])
def l_save_favourite():
    data = request.form.to_dict()
    
    favourite = Fav.query.filter_by(user_id=session['user_id']).first()
    if not favourite:
        # We don't know this user's favourite colour yet, add it
        favourite = Fav(user_id=session['user_id'],
                        color=data['currentColor'])
        db.session.add(favourite)
        db.session.commit()
    else:
         # We'll update their favourite
        favourite.color = data['currentColor']
    db.session.commit()
    return "Saved"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

There's a lot there, and still plenty more that could be implemented, but it's already getting too long. Hopefully you can run it and work through the individual points one-by-one.